# What DLNA transcode settings stream nicely to XMBC on the RPi?

Tags: kodi, streaming-video

I see a lot of questions on the best media server to run on the RPi.  I'm looking to set up a media server to run on my Windows 7 machine that can stream to XBMC running on my RPi.  (I know there are lots of choices there, and I'm sure many would work.)  I've had mixed results with Windows Media Player, with one video stuttering, and another pausing after 10 seconds.

Once the media server has been selected, whatever it may be, what are the suggested transcode settings that should be used with the RPi?  Do certain video and audio codecs easier for the RPi to digest, resulting in better streaming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I purchased the MPEG-2 and VC-1 licence keys from [the Raspberry Pi Store](http://www.raspberrypi.com/), and all my issues went away with the problematic videos.  I'm guessing it was in part to the MPEG-2 key, and in part to the many [OpenELEC](http://openelec.tv/) updates since asking the question.